# How to create new jsp files in structured project by maven?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, netbeans

It is technical question. I created maven project as I always do like this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.pack -DartifactId=ComPack
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I would like to convert this project to web-app project. So I created `web-app` folder and it's subfolder `WEB-INF` which contains: `web.xml`, `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, and also I need `JSP` file to represent my view. It seems I cannot find how to create it (through New File->.. there is not exist JSP wizards). So is any way to create it through `netbeans` **using maven structured project**?

Sorry if this is too basic question, but I cannot find information about this over the internet.

Comment: Why don't you use an archetype for a maven web project?

Comment: Ahh, I've never done this before. I find this: -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp

Comment: netbeans has a maven web project wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} -DartifactId={project-name} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

But if you are not opposed to using eclipse. Create a Maven project and choose the maven-archetype-webapp.

There is a comprehensive list of Archetypes here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List

[image]